# Is the webpage read? How can I save it to an excel file?

Tags: python, excel, beautifulsoup

I want to use Python to save the text contents of a webpage to an Excel file. As a newbie, below is so far I can work out and I am not sure if it's right.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

html = urlopen("http://www.chicagoreader.com").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

Does it look ok? What would be the next step to save the text contents into an Excel file automatically? I've installed xlutils but don't know how to work with it.

Could anybody help me here? Thanks.

Comment: you tell us if it looks okay. What happens if you print soup ? If you have the data you wan't there are a few libraries you can choose between to save them in an Excel file. What kind of Excel files are you thinking about ? If it has to look neat you could go with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to write into the excel file using python, you have several packages to choose from:

- [xlwt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt%E2%80%8E)
- [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [pyexcelerator](http://pyexcelerator.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

So, it depends on what kind of excel file it should be, `xls` or `xlsx`, do you need formatting, does speed matters etc.

Here's an example on how to write web page title to the (0,0) cell using `xlwt`:

```
import xlwt  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

html = urlopen("http://www.chicagoreader.com").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')

sheet.write(0, 0, soup.title.text)

workbook.save('output.xls')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please don't recommend pyExcelerator. It is old, buggy, and completely superseded by xlwt.